# JavaScript date as previous day ie a day - 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I am trying to save a specific format date in mongodb, but its saving a `day-1`

Example -

```
db.test.insert({name: "test1", dob: new Date(1986, 11, 30)})
```

But it is saving the date as `29 December 1986`, let me know what I am doing wrong.

Also I tried the same at [mongodb](http://try.mongodb.org/) but thr too its saving as `day - 1` i.e. a previous day.

Comment: Possibly because of the timezone you're in? Well it does work fine for me.

Comment: @freakish I thought so but even on my local system its giving the same..just confirming that I am not doing something foolish here

Comment: The correct format for submitting as UTC is new Date("1986-11-30"). What you are doing creates a local timezone date.

Comment: @NeilLunn man another time u proved your awesomeness :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timezones will always be an issue.

```
var dob = new Date();
dob.setUTCFullYear(1986);
dob.setUTCMonth(11);
dob.setUTCDate(30);
dob.setUTCHours(12); // just to be extra safe :p
db.test.insert({name:"test1", dob:dob});
```

Comment: why 12 for `setUTCHours` ? considering as a safe value as per the comment

Comment: I don't really know XD Something I started doing ages ago because I figured noon in UTC would be the one time that everyone is on the same day, but then someone told me that timezone offsets of 13 and 14 were a thing, so... feel free to ignore it.